# File Explorer filepath box taller than it should be

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, gui, vivaldi

I installed the Vivaldi browser onto my computer, and since doing this, the top of my file explorer has looked like this:

[image]

It's completely normal aside from the taller box around the `Search` box and the filepath.

This is not only in windows explorer.  Showing the Address toolbar on the taskbar yields the same result:

[image]

Originally, uninstalling the Vivaldi browser fixed this; however, now, no matter how many times I uninstall and reinstall the browser, these heights remain the same.

Just for reference, here is the normal height of the box:

[image]

Also, I am not referring to the ribbon.  I am specifically referring to the height of the highlighted section:
[image]

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Just to make sure - you did reboot your computer and it's still doing this?

Comment: Yes.  I have even made a new user, and the asthethic change remains the same.

Comment: Does changing DPI/scale settings cause any change? (Settings -> System -> Display -> Scale and Layout) Maybe try changing it to something else and then back to what it was previously.

Comment: Unfortunately, no fix.  The box shrinks, but it's still much larger than the text and icon.

Comment: I don't see anything abnormal in your images. Mine are the same.

Comment: Look at the height of the box with the filepath and the search box in the first and third pictures.

Comment: You know what - I think this may be a change introduced by a Windows update. I just noticed that all my Explorer windows look just like the "big" one you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unrelated to Vivaldi. A recent Windows update has introduced a "feature" where Windows Explorer embeds an UWP search field making use of the same updated backend as the taskbar's search box (with dropdown suggestions and such), and while they tried to make it look like a native Win32 widget, it still ends up having more padding than usual.

This was mentioned in the [Insider Build 18894](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/05/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-18894/) announcement:

> We’ve heard your feedback asking for increased consistency, and to make it easier to find your files. Over the next few days we’ll be starting to roll out a new File Explorer search experience – now powered by Windows Search. This change will help integrate your OneDrive content online with the traditional indexed results. This rollout will start with a small percent, and then we’ll increase the rollout to more Insiders as we validate the quality of the experience.
>
> What does that mean for you? Once you have the new experience, as you type in File Explorer’s search box, you’ll now see a dropdown populated with suggested files at your fingertips that you can pick from.

This means the feature was probably released as part of the Windows 10.1909 update.